# How can I Detect Play/Pause events of a video player in WKWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiwebview, wkwebview

Consider there's a youtube video being played within a web view, using embedded code,

```
let videoID = "oxtP3wxXlTA" // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxtP3wxXlTA

let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width=100% height=100% src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?modestbranding=1?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"


videoPlayerWebView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML as String, baseURL:Bundle.main.resourceURL )
```

is there any option to track the play or pause events of the video player, using native Swift code? I tried a lot of javascript codes, but that didn't work, I'm also in need of native swift or objectiveC code.

Other major concern is that, it can be any player, not just youtube player, need to track play/pause events from any sort of video player.

Can someone give me a lead on this? On how to track the events?

Answer (score 0):

Please use "YTPlayerView" from this url https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper
You can use following Enum from this library.

```
 typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, YTPlayerState) {
    kYTPlayerStateUnstarted,
    kYTPlayerStateEnded,
    kYTPlayerStatePlaying,
    kYTPlayerStatePaused,
    kYTPlayerStateBuffering,
    kYTPlayerStateQueued,
    kYTPlayerStateUnknown
};
```

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a code, which will listen to all the videos which are being played on a webview, not just Youtube. Please share if you have something related to that, thanks for your effort, though!